# Not able to find Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Webforms

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual Studio 2019 (16.9.29). I added the following extensions:
Microsoft Reporting Services Projects
Microsoft RDLC Report Designer
But when I try to install Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms, it doesn't find it. I receive this error:

Command:
NuGet\Install-Package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms -Version 150.1537.0

Result:

```
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms.150.1537.0' with respect to project 'RptViewer', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2'
NuGet\Install-Package : Package 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms 150.1537.0' is not found in the following primary source(s): 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft 
SDKs\NuGetPackages\'. Please verify all your online package sources are available (OR) package id, version are specified correctly.
At line:1 char:1
+ NuGet\Install-Package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

I try to add a Package source to https://NuGet.org directly, but I am not sure if i did it correctly.
I desintalled/reinstalled the extensions
I cannot find the package in the NuGet Package Manager either.

What can I do to find the package and install it?

Thanks for helping a beginner!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message shows that the package does not exist in your local package source (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
SDKs\NuGetPackages), check your Package Source in Tools > Options> NuGet Package Manager > Package Source.

What's your source link of Nuget.org? It should be `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json` like this:
[image]

You can install package use NuGet Package Manager (right click on the project and choose Manage NuGet Packages), and select the correct source link when searching for the packages:

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! This is the URL for NuGet that i was missing. The resolved the issue.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow! You don't need to answer the your own question  showing grateful. Just up the answer or comment the correct answer, if you have the permission.